# Aws S3 event notification mail for différent user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sns

we have an aws account with some s3 buckets that are used by several people. I would like to know if there is a way, and if so which ones, to configure an sns notification by email when a restore from s3 glacier deep archive is completed so that this email goes to the person who initiated the retrieval ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there in fact there are multiple ways to accomplish this. What you would want to do is to create an `Event Notification` for your bucket. This can be found in the console by going into the bucket `Properties` and pressing the `Create Event Notification` button.

You will be prompted to select the type of action for which you want to send notifications. You would want to select `s3:ObjectRestore:Completed`:

[image]

You will need destination for your events. For sending emails, one option would be to create an SNS topic and use that as a destination. This topic can be integrated with Amazon Simple Email Service (SES) which will be able to send mails.

Other option would be to select a Lambda function as destination and use that to send emails and do other automations.

> the problem is more, how as an admin can I configure the sending of mail to the user who initiated the restoration and only to him

In this case you would want to [enable Event Bridge integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide//enable-event-notifications-eventbridge.html) for your bucket. If you enable it, it will send events which contain `requester` who initiated the restore for an object (see event full event format [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide//ev-events.html)). Event Bridge can be also integrated with SNS or Lambda.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. the problem is more, how as an admin can I configure the sending of mail to the user who initiated the restoration and only to him? for example I have a bucket called "my bucket". user A initiates the restoration of file 1. then a user B initiates the restoration of file 2 present in this same bucket. I would like user A to receive an email when file 1 is restored and user B to receive an email when file 2 is restored.

Comment: In that case you would want to have integration with Event Bridge (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide//EventBridge.html).

Comment: So your Idea (i'm sorry but i'm new on aws and there are so much services with sometimes little différences...) is to use eventbridge to send an event when an object is restore but then ? 
I can't just create a sns topic as i need to enter the email adresse. So i need to let the rule trigger a lambda function and use this lambda function to get the email adress of the user who request the object S3 restoration and then through this lambda function send an email with ses ?

Comment: With event bridge i can get the id of the user who request the restoration, but i don't found how to use this id to obtain more informations. My users have tag with email adress, with the user name i can found this tag with the function get_user from python boto3, but how to do it with the id instead of the user name ?

Comment: These should be other stackoverflow question on their own. Please post them, so other people could help you as well.

Comment: Yes i dit it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71193967/aws-s3-event-get-user-name?noredirect=1#comment125845035_71193967) but i don't get a clear answer yet.