# Aws S3 event, get user name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have objects on S3 glacier deep archives. I want to send an email to the user who request the restoration when the restoration is complete.

For that, my idea is to use S3 event to trigger a lambda function, and use this lambda function to send email.

The issue is that i don't know how to found informations about the users who request the restoration. I found the id, but then, how to use the id ? If i have the username i Can easly found tag associated with this username (and so, the email adress as it's a tag of my users) but i don't know how to use the id to found the username.

If someone has an Idea ?

Comment: You might need to have users 'request' the restoration through your own code. That way, you'll know who requested it. You could then trigger the restoration, wait for it to be available, then notify the user.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found a solution, i don't know if it's the best, but at least it work for me:
As all my users as a tag "mail_adress" i can search this tag from the user id with this code:

```
import boto3


iam = boto3.client('iam')



response = iam.get_account_authorization_details(Filter=['User'])

for i in range(len(response['UserDetailList'])):
    if response['UserDetailList'][i]['UserId'] ==  id_user:
        for y in range(len(response['UserDetailList'][i]['Tags'])):
            if response['UserDetailList'][i]['Tags'][y]['Key'] == 'mail_adress':
                mail_adresse = response['UserDetailList'][i]['Tags'][y]['Value']

print(mail_adress)
```

Comment: Is there a direct way to get the username from an S3 upload event?